# Error in MySQL Syntax with WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

could you check and tell me where i have made a mistake?
Here is the code:

```
$sql = "SELECT prekės.* , CONCAT(vartotojai.name) as v_name
        FROM prekės 
            LEFT JOIN vartotojai
            ON vartotojai.V_ID=prekės.V_ID
        ORDER BY prekės.date
        LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit
        WHERE prekės.category='Telefonai'";
```

The error comes from the last line with `WHERE` clause.

Comment: `select from join where order limit`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clause order is incorrect : `WHERE` -> `ORDER` -> `LIMIT` :

```
$sql = "SELECT prekės.*
             , CONCAT(vartotojai.name) as v_name
        FROM prekės LEFT JOIN vartotojai ON vartotojai.V_ID=prekės.V_ID
        WHERE prekės.category='Telefonai'
        ORDER BY prekės.date
        LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit
       ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [the order](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html). `ORDER` and `LIMIT` should go after `WHERE`.

In order to ensure you are crafting well designed SQL, it is a good idea to check the link I provided. Once you get it, it's actually quite easy to understand the *why* of it.

Comment: Also `ORDER BY` has to be after `WHERE.